# How do I set Google login credentials as an environment variable (or "pass them to a method")?

Tags: ruby, google-sheets

The [documentation for the roo library](http://roo.rubyforge.org/) says that in order to use Google spreadsheets I need to

> set the environment variables ‘GOOGLE_MAIL’ and ‘GOOGLE_PASSWORD’ or
>   you pass the Google-name and -password to the Google#new method.

I'm new to Ruby, naively just tried to change the environment variable (on Windows) by [doing this in the system properties](http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm#0), but it seems that it's not environment variables in this sense (and I guess that'd be a bad way to store sensitive data anyway)

I've deleted the environment variables from my (user not system) settings again, so back to square one. How do I follow this instruction? I don't understand what it means by "pass the Google-name and Google-password to the Google#new method", I'm trying to run the line

```
oo = Roo::Google.new('"'+sheetfull'"')
```

and I could ask for the details in the program rather than changing system settings (to make it easier for other people to use my code) with something along these lines

```
puts "What's your email?"
GOOGLE_MAIL = gets
puts "What's your password?"
GOOGLE_PASSWORD = gets
```

so that these 'environment variables' are set up before the spreadsheet is called with `oo`, or else it results in an error.

I'm not quite sure how I'd tell it that they've been given though... I tried the code above but it's obviously initialising GOOGLE_MAIL and GOOGLE_PASSWORD as constants(?) that don't get "passed to any methods"

Sorry if I've worded this poorly, I'm still learning all the lingo! Feel free to call me out on any of the things I've named etc. etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set environment variables using the instructions here: https://superuser.com/questions/284342/what-are-path-and-other-environment-variables-and-how-can-i-set-or-use-them

Alternatively, you can pass the values you prepared to roo like so:

```
Roo::Google.new(sheetfull, user: GOOGLE_MAIL, password: GOOGLE_PASSWORD)
```